# Solve $y''-2y = 4x^2e^{x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to use variation of parameters:

$y_h = C_1e^{\sqrt{2}x} + C_2e^{-\sqrt{2}x}$. The wronskian I get to be $w = -2\sqrt{2}$, $w_1 = -4x^2e^{x^2}e^{-\sqrt{2}x}$ and $w_2 = 4x^2e^{x^2}e^{\sqrt{2}x}$.

Solving for $$u_1' = \frac{w_1}{w} \rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x^2e^{x^2-2\sqrt{x}}$$
$$u_1 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int x^2e^{x^2-\sqrt{2}x}dx$$

This integral seems like a headache. Is this right approach? Is there a trick to solving this with VOP?

Comment: $$4x^2\mathrm e^{x^2}=(\mathrm e^{x^2})''-2·\mathrm e^{x^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I= \int x^2e^{x^2-\sqrt{2}x}dx$$
Rewrite the integral as:
$$I= \dfrac 12\int (2xe^{x^2})(xe^{-\sqrt{2}x})dx$$
Integrate by part:
$$I= \dfrac 12e^{x^2}(xe^{-\sqrt{2}x})- \int ....dx$$
Then note that the second integral is easy it has the form:
$$I_2=\dfrac  {\sqrt 2}4\int e^{x^2-\sqrt 2 x}(2x-\sqrt 2)dx$$
$$\implies I_2= \dfrac  {\sqrt 2}4\int e^udu$$
Where $u=x^2-\sqrt 2 x$.